# Как сделать такое меню используя библиотеку Telebot?

Tags: python, telebot

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать подобное меню или помогите пожалуйста найти гайд, я не смог. Буду благодарен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это делается не через код, а через `BotFather`.

```
Edit Bot -> Edit Commands
```

Далее отпраляете сообщение со списком команд и их описанием:

```
newbot - create a new bot
mybots - edit your bots
```

И так далее...

Comment: Можно и через код, для этого есть метод [setMyCommands](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#setmycommands).